# Need to show the loading screen when view present iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, view, uiview, loading

In our project we have used the deep link activity. When the user clicks the deep link the user willl be navigate to the app and we have shown the loading screen while fetching all details from the API.

In the above case when the user clicks the app link the start screen has displayed for a second and showing the loading screen.   I need to show the loading screen when the user clicks the deep link and dismiss when we get success response instead of showing start screen for a second(We have 5 web service to call when deep link is clicked )from the API.

**NOTE:**

I have moved the below code to viewdidLoad,viewWillAppear and loadView in start screen.

```
UploadingView.sharedInstance.presentLoadingGif(currentView:view, gifImage: "")
```

I am able to reproduce using below scenario's and I am able to see start screen for a second and loading starts.

Install the app

Terminate the app
Click the deep link

I am able to see the start screen for a second.

Comment: What're *some hard case*?

Comment: When terminate the app after installing and click the deep link. @Itachi I have updated question too

Comment: What is UploadingView.sharedInstance ? May be method "presentLoadingGif" has some fade-in animation on appearance, so you can see the start screen for a second